# Selenium2 (Grid): Violently killing a browser session

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Some browsers like IE fail to close when calling webdriver.quit() if they a modal javascript alert is displayed at the time of closing.

Does Selenium2/Webdriver have a way of killing the browser off in such cases?  If such an occurrence happens, it messes up all subsequent tests on that browser.

Regards,

Mark

Comment: Selenium/WebDriver can do anything that Java can do.  So if you have a dedicated testing system, you could do something like add a cleanup step at the end of the tests that looks for active browser processes and forcibly kills any that it finds.  Of course, that might be a bit frustrating to run on a dev box if you happen to have your own IE processes running.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. I already have a custom service on each test node which does things that Selenium cannot do.  I'll add a killBrowsers function to it. I hope Grid realises the browser is dead and does its own house-cleaning though.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For IE, I've found it necessary to call RemoteWebDriver.Close() before RemoteWebDriver.Dispose(). I use webdriver from C# against Chrome, IE and FF, locally and remotely. While calling close before dispose is only necessary for IE, it doesn't do any harm with the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just kill the process:

Windows:

taskkill /f /im iexplore.exe

taskkill /f /im firefox.exe